# TideSDK get connected screen

Tags: javascript, html, tidesdk

Is there a possibility to get all screen connected to the pc ?

And list them in a row with small screenshots.

Also is it possible to open new window on specified screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issues, by making screenshot and calculating each window width.